# One form, many Model instances: JSON and AJAX (on Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

**Background**: (If you're lazy but still want to help try just skipping to Question below) I have a model Node with a one to many relationship with itself (i.e. a tree).  I would like to have a page where a user can work with the whole tree.  I will send the tree as a javascript object using JSON:

```
tree = <%= raw @node.to_json(:include => :nodes) %>
```

There be a form with fields corresponding to the properties of Node (name, position, date, etc.).  My question is: what is the best way to build this form so that I can work with all of the above nodes?

I will need some sort of widget for selecting a node.  For simplicity let's say its just a bunch of `<a>`s.

Clearly I will need javascript to populate the form with the selected node's data.  How do I then attach javascript to the `<a>` elements to populate the form with the JSON data?  For example I could have a recursive partial _write_node.html.erb:

```
<a onclick="loadNodeIntoForm("<%=str%>)">node.name</a>
<% for i in 0..node.nodes.size %>
    <%= render :partial => 'write_node', locals => { :node => node.nodes[i], :str => str + '.nodes[' + i.to_s + ']' } %>
<% end %>
```

that I call using

```
<%= render :partial => 'write_node', locals => { :node => @node, :str => 'tree.node' } %>
```

Or perhaps I could use a javascript to build the `<a>`s on the client side by traversing the `tree` which would avoid the hackish string concatenation above?  And I was thinking something like

```
function loadNodeIntoForm(node) {
    document.getElementById('node[name]').value = node.name;
    document.getElementById('node[date]').value = date.name;
    //etc.
}
```

Then I will also have javascript that will update the JSON objects when the form is edited.

**Question:** Lastly, how can I use AJAX to save objects without using the form?  For example I want the user to be able to edit several nodes before saving so I can't just use ajax on the form, which would only submit the currently edited node.  Is it possible to simply POST a json object?

Comment: Just realized that to_json(:include => :nodes) only does one level.  It looks like I can manually specify more, but I probably need to write a function or partial to do the whole tree?

Comment: I'm guessing writing a method saveNode(node) which creates a custom ajax call, perhaps using JQuery.ajax() is the way to go on Question 2? Do I need to worry about authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the lazy route and skipped down to your question.  AJAX has no direct relation to forms.  You could just post the JSON object.  Use [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: Excuse the silly/rambling question.  I  just needed to get my thoughts straight for this project.  Thanks for confirming them!